# execute sparql query for dbpedia Endpoint

Tags: c#, sparql, dbpedia, dotnetrdf

I am trying to execute a SPARQL query for DBpedia endpoint using this C# code:

```
 try
        {
            SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://dbpedia.org/sparql"), "http://dbpedia.org");
            string query = "SELECT ?artist ?album WHERE { ?album d:producer :Timbaland .  ?album d:musicalArtist ?artist . }";
            SparqlResultSet rset = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet(query);
            foreach (SparqlResult result in rset.Results)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

I am still getting an exception

> A HTTP Error occurred while trying to make the SPARQL Query, see inner exception for details

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is that all the error message says?  Do you have access to the HTTP error code?  It does say "see inner exception for details".  What details does the [inner exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) provide?

Comment: Your query isn't right either;  if you paste it into the public endpoint you'll see [an error message](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fartist+%3Falbum+WHERE+%7B+%3Falbum+d%3Aproducer+%3ATimbaland+.++%3Falbum+d%3AmusicalArtist+%3Fartist+.+%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on) that the prefix `d:` is not defined.  I recommend that you debug your queries with the interactive interfaces before you hard code them into application.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is reasonably descriptive, like it says see the inner exception for details which will give you the .Net `WebException` that occurred which may allow you to get access to the .Net `WebResponse` if available which will give you access to things like Response Code and Body.

As @Joshua Taylor points out your actual query is invalid in this case.

Also it may be worth reading the dotNetRDF [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki) on [Debugging HTTP Communication](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/HowTo/Debug%20HTTP%20Communication.wiki#!debugging-http-communication)